# RubyMine fails to start on Yosemite

Tags: webstorm, rubymine, osx-yosemite

RubyMine won't start under Yosemite, no loading screen, no error message.

This seems to be caused by the default JVM that comes with Yosemite

**EDIT** This also seems to affect WebStorm

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### This solution is controversial - please read all of it before applying changes!

Open this file

Check the version of Java, most likely 1.8, by using `java -version`, you should see something like:

```
java version "1.8.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_20-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.20-b23, mixed mode)
```

Open and edit

```sh
/Applications/RubyMine.app/Contents/Info.plist
```

Or for WebStorm

```sh
/Applications/WebStorm.app/Contents/Info.plist
```

Update the following key

```xml
<key>JVMVersion</key>
<string>1.7*</string>
```

to

```xml
<key>JVMVersion</key>
<string>1.8*</string>
```

RubyMine should now be good to go

---

### Feedback on this solution

JetBrains do not recommend this solution as it will break autoupdating with **patches**.  That tradeoff was acceptable for me as I just wanted to get going quickly and avoid installing Java 1.6.

The full discussion is here https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/27854363-IDE-doesn-t-start-after-updating-to-Mac-OS-Yosemite-or-Mavericks

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't edit your plist file since it will prevent Rubymine from autoupdating. This is direct from their support pages:

> Modifying Info.plist will break the application digital signature and prevent the patch updates. We do not recommend modifying Info.plist file to run under JDK 1.7 or 1.8.

Page located here:

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/27854363-IDE-doesn-t-start-after-updating-to-Mac-OS-Yosemite-or-Mavericks

The correct answer is to install [Apple JDK 1.6](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572)

Comment: I don't disagree, but having to install java 1.6 is a pain and the .plist change is a quick fix to get things going.  I'll update my answer to reflect this feedback.

Comment: Why is it a pain to install Java 1.6? You download the file and double-click, what's so painful?

Comment: the link to Apple JDK is broken

Comment: Is it possible to keep Oracle JDK 1.8 since that's what I develop with in Eclipse? I would need Java 6 only for Rubymine 6.3.3.

Answer (score 4):

JDK 1.6 is required to run and may be missing on your system. Please install Apple JDK 1.6. There should be a window with the suggestion to install Java when you start the product for the first time, but it could be hidden by other application windows.

Apple JDK 1.6 download: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572.

I have tried to down load the JDK 1.6, it works in my Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Just install java for OS X, and it'll solve the issue.

Up till OS X El Capitan(10.11), [this](https://support.apple.com/kb/dl1572?locale=en_US) link solves. Or you can just google "java for osx", most probably first link will show you the right answer.