# Can't start RubyMine from app icon after upgrade, only from command line

Tags: osx-yosemite, rubymine

I just upgraded my RubyMine to v8.0.0 with the custom bundled JDK. After installing it I tried to open the app from it's icon and nothing happened. I mean it showed me the dialog box if I trust the app (this happens whenever you want to open a new installed app for the first time), but afterwards nothing showed up.

I looked through the app processes, and couldn't find the RubyMine app. I also tried the solution from this question:

[RubyMine fails to start on Yosemite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26422750/rubymine-fails-to-start-on-yosemite)

No success.

After I ran `chmod +x /Applications/RubyMine.app/Contents/MacOS/rubymine`, I tried again from the app icon, but it still doesn't seem to work.

I updated my java version to `java version "1.8.0_65"` and still no luck.

It works when I run `/Applications/RubyMine.app/Contents/MacOS/rubymine` from the command line.

Just to be clear, before upgrading to v8.0 this problem didn't occur.

I run OS X Yosemite.

Any ideas what can cause this issue?

[UPDATE] I ended up downgrading to v7.1.4 until this gets solved.

Comment: Have you tried RubyMine 8.0.1? If it fails the same, is there something in idea.log?

Comment: I just installed v8.0.1 and I still have the same problem. Where can I find the idea.log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. Looks like I had to run the app in 64-bit mode.

Right click app icon -> Get Info -> "Open in 32-bit mode" must be unchecked.